# Migration from PostgreSQL 8.3 to 9.1

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem with migration from PostgreSQL 8.3 to 9.1

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_upgrade -d /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -b /usr/lib/postgresql/8.3/bin -B /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin -k -v
Running in verbose mode
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking current, bin, and data directories                 ok
Checking cluster versions
Old cluster data and binary directories are from different major versions.
Failure, exiting
```

Anyone can help ? Thx

Comment: Did you see the limitations on `pg_upgrade` for 8.3: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html#AEN153788

Comment: What's the output of `cat /var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main/PG_VERSION` and of `/usr/lib/postgresql/8.3/bin/postgres --version`?

Answer (score 5):

I thought you couldn't do a binary upgrade from 8.3 to anything; that `pg_upgrade` supported *8.4 or newer*. However it turns out [8.3 is supported with a bunch of extra restrictions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html#AEN153788).

If you can't use `pg_upgrade` you must do a dump and reload to upgrade. If you're going to have to do a dump and reload, you might as well do it straight to 9.3, there's no point dumping and reloading to 8.4 then using `pg_upgrade`.

**Read the upgrade section of the release notes for every major version between your current one and the target version before upgrading**. So read the 8.4, 9.0, 9.1, 9.2 and 9.3 release notes' upgrading/compatibility sections. Make sure you are aware of things like the `standard_conforming_strings` change, `bytea_output` default change, etc and how they will affect your program.

Also ensure your client drivers (psqlODBC, PgJDBC, nPgSQL, Python's `psycopg2`, or whatever) are up to date when upgrading, preferably as new as or newer than the PostgreSQL database release you are going to be using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But are you sure ! have a look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgupgrade.html pg_upgrade supports upgrades from 8.3.X and later to the current major release of PostgreSQL, including snapshot and alpha releases.

Comment: @oussemos Whoops, yeah - I'm wrong, I thought it was from 8.4, but 8.3 is supported with a bunch of extra limits.